# Javascript countdown timer to change image and link

Tags: javascript, countdown

Apologies in advance for being somewhat out of my depth here.

I am trying to use a JavaScript countdown timer on an ASP page to do the following - every sixty seconds after the a page loads, an image-based link will switch between one of five image/link combinations.

I've done something somewhat wrong here, and I can't find the problem.  It never runs.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

The images are named the following:

- 1_AdvoImg.gif 2_AdvoImg.gif 3_AdvoImg.gif 4_AdvoImg.gif 5_AdvoImg.gif

The urls are the following:

- linkone.html linktwo.html linkthree.html linkfour.html linkfive.html

The html encapsulating the link is this:

```
<a id='AdvoLink' href='../'><img id='AdvoImg' src='' border="0"></a>
```

The javascript is this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function startTimer(duration) {
        var timer = duration, seconds, imgprefix, imgname, linkurl;
        imgprefix = 1;

        setInterval(function () {
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            imgname = imgprefix.concat("_AdvoImg.gif");

            if (imgprefix == 1) {
                linkurl = "linkone.html";
            }

            if (imgprefix == 2) {
                linkurl = "linktwo.html";
            }

            if (imgprefix == 3) {
                linkurl = "linkthree.html";
            }

            if (imgprefix == 4) {
                linkurl = "linkfour.html";
            }

            if (imgprefix == 5) {
                linkurl = "linkfive.html";
            }

            if (--timer <= 0) {
                document.getElementById("AdvoLink").href = "";
                document.getElementById("AdvoImg").src = imgname;
                ++imgprefix;
                timer = duration;
            }
        }, 5);
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        startTimer(60);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Unit for second param for `setInterval` is millisecond. So, if you want it to run every 60 secs, you should set 60000.

Comment: wheen you're setting var timer that should be a `;` as you are current setting timer to  `duration, seconds, imgprefix, imgname, linkurl`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build a timer inside a timer there.
Try keeping it as simple as possible.
   What you actually need is just:

```
window.onload = function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    //your url changing magic here - without the timer stuff
  }, 60000); 
};
```

With this, your magic code should trigger every 60000 milliseconds => 60s => 1minute.
You could actually kinda "debug" it by using console.log() inside your loop.

Answer (score 0):

dunno what you were using var seconds for so I removed it

edited to stop image number going over 5, change if loop to whatever number you need

```js
function startTimer(duration) {
  
        var timer = duration;var seconds;var imgprefix;var imgname;var linkurl;
        imgprefix = 1;
    
  
   

        setInterval(function() {
      
     
       
            imgname = imgprefix+"_AdvoImg.gif";

            if (imgprefix == 1) {
                linkurl = "linkone.html";
            }

            if (imgprefix == 2) {
                linkurl = "linktwo.html";
            }

            if (imgprefix == 3) {
                linkurl = "linkthree.html";
            }

            if (imgprefix == 4) {
                linkurl = "linkfour.html";
            }

            if (imgprefix == 5) {
                linkurl = "linkfive.html";
            }
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=timer;
              timer--;
            if (timer <= 0) {
              
                document.getElementById("AdvoLink").href = linkurl;
                document.getElementById("AdvoImg").src = imgname;
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "image src = "+imgname+" and href = "+linkurl;
                if(imgprefix < 5){++imgprefix;}else{imgprefix =1;}
                timer = duration;
            }
        }, 200//speed up and slow down here, in milliseconds
                   );
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        startTimer(10);
    };
```

```html
<a id='AdvoLink' href='../'><img id='AdvoImg' src='' border="0"></a>
<div id="timer"> </div>
<div id='result'> </div>
```